# communication between spring instances behind a load balancer

Tags: spring, load-balancing

I have a few instances of Spring apps running behind a load balancer. I am using EHCache as a caching system on each of these instances.

Let's say I receive a request that is refreshing a part of the cache on one instance. I need a way to tell the other instances to refresh their cache (or to replicate it).

I'm more interested in a solution based on Spring and not just cache replication and that's because there are other scenarios similar with this one that require the same solution.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There is no simple Spring solution for this. Depends on the requirements. You can use any kind of PubSub like a JMS topic to notify your nodes. This way the problem can be that you cannot guarantee consistency. The other nodes can still read the old data for a while. In my current project we use Redis. We configured it as cache with [Spring Data Redis](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-redis/) and theres no need to notify the other nodes since the cache is shared. In non cache scenarios we also use redis as a PubSub service.